# Pass an extra parameter to make

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a Makefile like this:

```
baud=19200
src=dimmer
avrType=attiny13
programmerDev=/dev/ttyUSB003
programmerType=stk500v1

object:
        avr-gcc -g -DF_CPU=$(avrFreq) -Wall -Os -mmcu=$(avrType) -c -o $(src).o $(src).cpp

read:
        @for memory in calibration eeprom efuse flash fuse hfuse lfuse lock signature application apptable boot prodsig usersig; do \
                avrdude -p $(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) -b$(baud) -v -U $$memory:r:./$(avrType).$$memory.hex:i; \
        done
```

Which works as intended. When I type `make read` several files are extracted from the microcontroller. This can take a little while because of the slow connection and data size, so I was thinking it would be nice to be able to just type `make read flash`, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Of course I can make entries like `read_flash`, `read_hfuse` ... but I have a feeling it can be done smarter.

I also want to be able to run a command like `make read all` which will execute every file in turn from the controller.

Now I am new to creating Makfile's, so maybe I am on the wrong track all together. Please feel free to explain how it should be done.

I am on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a highly GNU-specific makefile is acceptable to you (and I'd argue that it's much better to use a portable `make`, such as GNU's, than writing portable makefiles), you can implement this rather easily:

```
ALL = calibration eeprom efuse flash fuse hfuse lfuse lock signature \
      application apptable boot prodsig usersig

ifeq (read,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  WANT := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
  ifneq ($(WANT),)
    $(eval $(WANT):;@:)
  endif
  UNKNOWN := $(filter-out $(ALL),$(WANT))
  ifneq ($(UNKNOWN),)
    $(error Invalid arguments: $(UNKNOWN))
  endif
endif

read-one = avrdude -p $(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) \
        -b$(baud) -v -U $1:r:./$(avrType).$1.hex:i

.PHONY: read
read:
    $(foreach w,$(or $(WANT),$(ALL)),$(call read-one,$w) &&) :
```

If the first argument in the command line is "read", this sets the `WANT` variable to the list of arguments after the first. It then turns those names into no-op targets and makes the `read` target invoke the `read-one` function for each name, or for `$(ALL)` if no name was specified.

I use variations of this quite often, for things like `make print VARIABLE...`, which will just print `$(VARIABLE)` or `make help TOPIC` to display information about a target.

Comment: I don't get your first sentence, can you please clarify it a bit? "If a highly GNU-specific makefile is acceptable to you (and I'd argue that it's much better to use a portable make, such as GNU's, than writing portable makefiles),"

Comment: This answer contains a makefile that will only work in GNU make. In that sense it's not "portable". I was also saying that this is not necessarily a bad thing, because instead of writing a portable makefile, it's better to target a portable `make` program. See the first entry in [Paul's Rules of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would do: `make flash` or `make hfuse` or `make all` with the following Makefile:

```
baud=19200
avrType=attiny13
programmerDev=/dev/ttyUSB003
programmerType=stk500v1

all: calibration eeprom efuse flash fuse hfuse lfuse lock signature \
    application apptable boot prodsig usersig

%:
        avrdude -p $(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) -b$(baud) \
        -v -U $@:r:./$(avrType).$$memory.hex:i || rm ./$(avrType).$@.hex;
```

This is probably not portable Make, but it works in gnu make.  This does not allow any other rules, but you could name this file `read` and do `make -f read flash`.  That would allow other rules to be placed in other make files.

Notice that this is not particularly safe, since it will run avrdude on `make foo`.  To get tighter control of the targets, you can do:

```
.SUFFIXES: .ph
.PHONY: efuse.ph eeprom.ph ...
all: efuse eeprom ...
.ph:
        avrdude ...
```

This way, only the targets listed as PHONY will be valid targets.

Comment: This is definitely not portable: the behavior of any target containing `%` is implementation defined.

Comment: Thnx. The problem is that there actually *are* a handful of other rules in the Makefile which I left out for readability. I updated the question with that. I would really like to fit all rules in one single Makefile.

Comment: As far as portability is concerned, the `for` loop isn't terribly portable either ;o) I was hoping to make it a bit more portable at the same time.

Comment: I have to check this .PHONY stuff, don't understand how it works (yet).

Answer (score 1):

What about making the list of modules a configurable list with a default:

```
LIST = calibration eeprom efuse flash fuse \
       hfuse lfuse lock signature application \
       apptable boot prodsig usersig

read:
        @for memory in $(LIST); do \
             avrdude -p $(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) \
               -b$(baud) -v -U $$memory:r:./$(avrType).$$memory.hex:i; \
        done
```

And then call make either as `make` for the default, or `make LIST="eeprom efuse"` for just two modules.